# Using translation with jquery in prestashop

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, prestashop

I'm trying to translate some terms when I'm using jQuery inside a smarty file. 
This is my jQuery code:

```
else {
    $("#message").val("{l s='Please try to be clear.'}");
```

This phrase appears exactly as `{l s='Please try to be clear.'}` in my web page and doesn't take into consideration the translation mode.

I know that i can use js=1 when i'm inside a javascript code but it doesn't work for me neither.
Does anyone have an idea about how to use the translation in a jQuery function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to use `{literal}` tags around JS blocks:

```
{literal}
<script>
/...
</script>
{/literal}
```

But when you need to insert some smarty into JS block, it won't work;
To make it work you have to do the close and reopen tags (looks like a little bit of a hack :)

```
{literal}
<script>
   var txt = '{/literal}{l s='Some text'}{literal}'
</script>
{/literal}
```

Also in PrestaShop templates you'll find;

```
{strip}
{addJsDefL name=translation_6}{l s='Not found' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{/strip}
```

Which will create

```
var translation_6 = 'Not found';
```

in your body, which will you be able to use

Comment: there is a little problem : when i do the translation it doesn't take into account the special characters

Comment: That's probably a separate question. What kind of characters? Special characters can be problematic, yes and they should be avoided in translations

Comment: like 'é' or 'ç' when i translate it is encoded but only for the messages included in the javascript, the other translations work fine with special characters

Answer (score 1):

Maybe enclosing your JS script in [literal](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal) will help:

```
{literal}

//JS code

{/literal}
```